# What does the yellow dot next to a dungeon indicate?

Tags: diablo-iv

I've noticed that some dungeons have a yellow dot next to their symbol on the world map, but I'm not sure what this indicates. I know the chest icon indicates you've yet to complete this dungeon with a character on this realm, but I'm not sure about the yellow dot icon.

**What does the yellow dot icon displayed next to dungeons on the world map indicate?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The yellow dot indicates a dungeon that your current character hasn't beaten, but another one of your characters on the same realm has beaten it. In other words, you've already unlocked the Dungeon Aspect reward for these dungeons, but you can still complete them for the Renown on this character.

Comment: This took me way longer to realize than I'd like to admit. I was thrown off since I thought dungeon renown was shared  between characters, but after some switching between characters I realized I was wrong.